# $P(X_1<X_2)$ where $X_i$ is exponential and independent - not sure of my solution.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

We have two independent random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, with law $Exp(\rho_i)$ respectively.
I want to find the probability of the following event $\{X_1<X_2\}$.

Is the following correct?

$P(X_1<X_2)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{x_2=x_1}\rho_1\rho_2 e^{-(\rho_1x_1+\rho_2x_2)}dx_2dx_1=\int_0^\infty-\rho_1[e^{-(\rho_1x_1+\rho_2x_2)}]_0^{x_2=x_1}dx_1=-\rho_1[-\frac{1}{\rho_1+\rho_2}e^{-(\rho_1+\rho_2)x_1}+\frac{1}{\rho_1}e^{-\rho_1x_1}]^\infty_0=1-\frac{\rho_1}{\rho_1+\rho_2}$

Is this solution correct?

Comment: Why would you think it should be $\frac 12$?  The distributions might be very different.  Granted, if $p_1=p_2$ then symmetry gives us $\frac 12$ but in that case you get $1-\frac {p_1}{2p_1}=1-\frac 12=\frac 12$ as you'd expect.

Comment: Yes I realized that a second after posting I edited it!

Comment: And as the posted solution has remarked, you are mixing up $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Comment: So then the answer seems correct right :) ?

Comment: No.  You computed $P(X_2<X_1)$.  But otherwise, the computation is good.  If $p_1$ is very big  we expect $X_1$ to occur first.

Comment: Ah yes I see thanks lulu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $\frac  1 2$ if $\rho_1=\rho_2$, not in general. ALlso you computed $P(X_2 <X_1)$ instead of $P(X_1<X_2)$. So the correct answer is $\frac {\rho_1} {\rho_1+\rho_2}$.